# How to dump type hierarchy of a C/C++ compilation unit in LLVM

Tags: c++, c, types, llvm

I want to dump the type hierarchy of a C/C++ compilation unit in LLVM. For example, consider this C code:

```
struct S {
  int a[3];
  char *s; 
};

struct T {
  float f;
  struct S t; 
};
```

I want to get a type hierarchy graph like this:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it for development purpose (i.e. generating an UML model), for debugging purpose (exploring a compiled structure) or something else?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have to disagree with the closure of this question. Contrary to the stated reason for closure, it does not lack focus at all. It asks a single question, and is completely clear about what it's asking. He's provided a sample input, and the desired output for that input (modulo a typo or two). There's nothing unfocused about the question at all.

Comment: But since it probably won't be reopened: at least what's easily available from Clang is a textual output that represents the structures in something roughly like XML.You pass the ast-dump flag directly to clang, and it'll produce an output. Here's a run for your sample input: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07e37f4204c4db76

Comment: @JerryCoffin Completely agree with you and voted for reopen.

Comment: "I want X. Please provide code." is a valid reason to close.

Comment: @usr2564301 actually he provided the code before wanting X. And X could be a tool.

Answer (score 0):

First, the type hierarchy is not such a thing.  It doesn't have tree form, there are unrelated types that can be linked together in absolutely no form... and there are recursive definitions that will make your tree to become a graph (you can get very complicated ones).  There's nothing in the compiler, but to detect programming errors and to create the code that your program will use... Some have a program lister, that beautifies your code in some way, but in general you get a much harder listing to parse.  Information (semantic, structural) gets lost in the compiling process.

So the only way to do what you want is to parse the source code in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a parser for `clang -ast-dump` that emits a .`dot` (DOT is a simple graph description language) file where a node could represent a `Decl` AST node and have an incoming edge when it is a child of another `Decl` AST node. You could then pipe the `.dot` file to any any dot renderer, like my favorite, `xdot`